# VB6 App Icon - pixelated

Tags: vb6

I have an icon that has 32 (256x256, 48x48, 32x32, 16x16), 8 (256x256, 48x48, 32x32, 16x16) and 4 (32x32, 16x16) bit icons.

I have specified that I want to use my icon for the form and application itself and for some reason, after I run application and once i am in the application, rather than using nice icon application uses 4bit icon for all areas?

---

I happen to find this article:
http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Tips/Setting_the_App_Icon_Correctly/article.asp

It doesn't seem to explain easily on how to create an RC and RES file

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the best approach is to only have one icon image per icon file. If you expect the icon to show as a 16x16 then provide a .ico file with a 16x16 icon in (say) 8-bit colour. That way VB has to use the icon you provide. It may mean you end up with a few file versions (16x16, 32x32) of the same icon but it makes like much easier.